# Реально ли сделать "умную" 3D-модель на three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, 3dsmax

Мне нужно решить следующую задачу!
У меня есть окно, в котором отображается 3D-модель предоставленная мне в формате .dae и запущенная при помощи Collada. Её фоном является стрим с моей web-камеры.
Реализована возможность определения лица пользователя в этом стриме. Реально ли влиять как то на модель при определении лица? Тоесть, к примеру, лицо пользователя определилось в определённых координатах окна, мне нужно что бы моя модель (у меня слон), повернул голову и посмотрел в ту область координат, где находится моя голова. Или же взмахнул хоботом на ту область координат и т.д.
Буду благодарен любым ответам, так как сам в этом деле новичок

Comment: Stackoverflow немного про другое :) Тут задают вопрос про конкретную проблему и получают конкретный ответ. Широкие вопросы, типа этого, лучше задавать на форуме https://discourse.threejs.org/ (он хоть и англоязычный, но народ там доброжелательный :) )

Comment: Что-то типа такого? http://west77.ru/content/r72/tracking_skull.html Сделано в достаточно старой ревизии r72. В последних ревизиях сделать такое - на порядок проще.

Answer (score 1):

Это реально. Есть много примеров анимации в сети, например, https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_animation_skinning_blending и захваченная kinect анимация, перенесенная на частицы https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_kinect.html
Все что нужно это запускать желаемую анимацию на основании нужного вам события. Можно использовать сторонние библиотеки типа https://trackingjs.com/
Подробнее о системе анимации в three.js на сайте https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/introduction/Animation-system

Пример анимации с использованием скелета и костей https://threejs.org/docs/#api/objects/SkinnedMesh

Comment: Я по такому же принципу и делал. Но вопрос немного в другом. Мне не нужно запускать готовую анимацию модели. Мне нужно что бы модель, в зависимости от полученных координат местоположения лица (используется tracking.js) сама выбрала лучшую траекторию направления костей в ту точку и это выглядело плавно как анимация

Comment: Что вам мешает двигать сами кости модели в three.js изменяя позицию и повороты?

Comment: Ознакомьтесь с примером https://threejs.org/docs/#api/objects/SkinnedMesh

Comment: ничего не мешает. Но как выбрать нужную траекторию для анимации? Все 3 оси должны же как то взаимодейтвовать и зависеть одна от одной при анимации. Иначе получится каша. Я про это

Comment: "лицо пользователя определилось в определённых координатах окна", определяете примерные координаты где находится лицо пользователя и поворачиваете части модели в ту сторону. Или я не верно понимаю чего вы хотите добиться?

Comment: В рамках Stackoverflow вопрос ни разу не конкретный и ответ такой же - ни о чем. Все, что нужно сделать, это знать координаты лица на экране, затем преобразовать его координаты в координаты NDC (см пример для THREE.Raycaster() - как там преобразуются координаты мыши), после чего использовать THREE.Raycaster() в связке с THREE.Plane(), чтобы узнать точку, куда должна смотреть/махать хоботом/указывать ушами модель в рамках сцены. Весь диалог в комментариях сейчас - из пустого в порожнее.

Comment: всё правильно. Простосто если к примеру мне нужно повернуть голову вправо и чуть вверх поднять. Тогда по идее нужно изменить положение модели по отношению к оси Y и X, но как сильно менять это положение,  с какой плавностью. То есть в конечном итоге программист не должен управлять моделью. Она сама должна понимать куда поворачивать кости, какие именно кости. Как быстро и т.д.

Comment: Вопрос стоял так: "Возможно?" я ответил "Да", уважаемый prisoner849. А как именно это сделать — нужны подробности в самом вопросе, сама сцена с чем работает человек, задавший вопрос. Куски кода..

Comment: @Pavel Вот именно, поэтому я и не пишу ответ, а пишу комментарии, так как конкретной информации связанной с конкретной проблемой - ноль (только пространные размышления на широкую тему), следовательно, ценность ответа на такой вопрос - ноль.